# How to make a sticky footer, whilst keeping the wrapper dynamic?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, sticky-footer

Well, I was stressed. - BIG time.

I googled around on the net for ages looking for a neat sticky footer. Well, guess what. Every sticky footer I found told you to use `min-height:100%`. This was annoying because it made your wrapper ugly, removing the dynamic height if the content was smaller than the window itself.

So the question is **How do you make a sticky footer, whilst keeping the wrapper dynamic?**

Comment: http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/using-sticky-footer-code.html No need for JS. Your wrapper is exactly that a wrapper, it really doesn't need any styling so I am having a hard time understanding your issue. If you have background colours or something like that apply them to a div INSIDE the wrapper and use the wrapper for what it was intended, to contain all your other code and allow you to manipulate it as a whole.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a neat little javascript trick that allows you to make a sticky footer that stays at the bottom of the window when the content is smaller than the window. Then when the content is higher than the window, it puts the footer to the bottom of the page!

```
setInterval(function(){
    var wrapper_height = $('#wrapper').height();

var window_height = $(window).height();
    if(wrapper_height<window_height){
        $('footer').css({position:'absolute', bottom: '0px'});
    }else if(wrapper_height>window_height){
        alert('switched to mode 2');
         $('footer').css({position:'relative', bottom: '0px'});
    }
},10);



$('#wrapper').click(function(){

    $('#wrapper').append('<p>BLAH</p>');

})
```

​

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

By keeping the wrapper dynamic - I think you mean the wrapper of the page/main content, not the footer? Does the footer height need to be dynamic or just the whole page height?

If the footer is fixed height but the main content wrapper can vary, this is a good resource:
http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/

Comment: that requires you to restrict the height of the wrapper.

Comment: Yes - you are right, I seemed to have missed that part of it.